# The dialog can't pop up when the date validation is invalid

Tags: php, ajax, validation, yii

I am a new Yii user, I have a problem when I would like to build a website.
My website has a part which is required the user input the start date and end date, I want to have one function, if the end date is set before the start date, it will show a dialog box to warn the user automatically, but I can't do that. Have any idea to do that?

Here is my code of the two date text fields:

```
<td>Start
    <?php 

            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'name'=>'COURSE_START_DATE',
            'model'=>$Cmodel,
            'attribute'=>'COURSE_START_DATE',
            'language'=>Yii::app()->language=='en_us',

            'options'=>array(
                'showAnim'=>'fold', // 'show' (the default), 'slideDown', 'fadeIn', 'fold'
                'showOn'=>'button', // 'focus', 'button', 'both'
                'buttonText'=>Yii::t('ui','Calendar'),
                'buttonImage'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/calendar.png',
                'buttonImageOnly'=>true,
            ),
    )
        ?></td>

     <td>End 
    <?php 
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            'name'=>'COURSE_END_DATE',
            'model'=>$Cmodel,
            'attribute'=>'COURSE_END_DATE',
            'language'=>Yii::app()->language=='en_us',
            'options'=>array(
                'showAnim'=>'fold', // 'show' (the default), 'slideDown', 'fadeIn', 'fold'
                'showOn'=>'button', // 'focus', 'button', 'both'
                'buttonText'=>Yii::t('ui','Calendar'),
                'buttonImage'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/calendar.png',
                'buttonImageOnly'=>true,

            ),
        ));

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are really new to yii, you'll have to learn a bunch of stuff:

**1. How to perform ajax and client validation in yii:**

In your form you'll need to indicate that ajax and the client validation might be performed. Here's an example:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'contacts-form',
  'enableAjaxValidation'=>true, // this turns on AJAX validation
  'enableClientValidation'=>true, // this turns on Client validation
)); ?>
```

**2. Enable the ajax validation in your controller**

For example in your controller action call:

```
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

With:

```
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='contacts-form') {
    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
    Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

**3. Create the validation rule in your model**

Then you need to create the validation rule that'll compare your two values. To do it you can use the build in [CCompareValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCompareValidator) by changing the default operator to '>' for example.
So in your model you'll have something like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        //your other rules
        array('COURSE_END_DATE', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'COURSE_START_DATE', 'operator' => '>'),
    );
}
```

Comment: If I would like to use CJuiDialog to do the thing what I want to do, how can I do that? thank you for your all kind answer and sorry for my bad English.